# Relation Between Isometries in Manifolds and Dynamical Systems

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, dynamical-systems, isometry, diffeomorphism

I would like to get more clearly if there is a relation between those topics in the sense I am about to describe.

I've been briefly studying integral curves, flows, and one-parameter groups of diffeomorphisms on manifolds for a General Relativity course, related to Killing Vector Fields. Since the study of dynamical systems also deals with flows, I was wondering in what ways can we trace parallels between those areas.

I apologize if this is something trivial, I just wanted to have some brainstorming ideas of interesting topics to study relating those subjects.
Feel free to just make any observations.

Comment: One-parameter groups of diffeomorphisms are examples of continuous-time dynamical systems. Did you just want confirmation of this or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: The confirmation sure is nice. Just wondering if there is any use in studying those manifolds in General relativity from the dynamic systems perspective.

Comment: Poincare more or less founded the study of dynamical systems to understand classical mechanics, and in particular orbital mechanics. You can read about some details of the history here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/History_of_dynamical_systems